# Boundary behaviour of a mechanical wave

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, reflection, string

Let us assume we have a taut rope and I introduce a pulse in it by whipping one end. Now if instead of a clamp, I have tied the other end of the rope to a denser rope, a part of the energy is transmitted as a pulse in the denser rope and a part of it is reflected. Why is a part of this energy reflected? Why can't this part of the energy just be used as a part of the pulse in the denser rope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy is reflected due to the discontinuity of the string [mechanical impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_impedance). Therefore it "can't be used as a part of the pulse" because it never gets to the denser rope.

It's actually a special case of very general principle: whenever there is a discontinuity in propagation medium, energy reflection occurs. That's the same in optics, when you are considering energetic losses in transmitted light due to the highly refractive (i.e. with high refractive index) lenses.

Comment: So can I "blame" this on the greater inertia of the denser rope ?

Comment: Yes, you can. [...just to add the characters...]